Angular bindingcan't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of input after upgraded angular 15 to 16
`I am doing angular application migration 14 to 16. First i converted 14 to 15 it's working fine. then i converted angular 15 to 16 here i got error.
can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of input. Same for 'ngModel' options.
Here i added my package.json
{
  "name": "tac",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=32768 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@3dgenomes/ngx-resizable": "^1.8.1",
    "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^27.3.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^27.3.0",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^27.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.2.0",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.4",
    "ace-builds": "^1.32.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^27.3.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^27.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "13.0.0",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "^6.0.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "angular-highcharts": "^13.0.1",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.2",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^10.3.3",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.4.9",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jasypt": "^1.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-content-loading": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-markdown": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-markdown-editor": "^4.3.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^11.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^13.0.0",
    "npm": "^10.8.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.6",
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^16.9.10-lts",
    "quill": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.0",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^16.2.3",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "sha.js": "^2.4.11",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}`

I need to convert angular 15 version to 16 version with properly my application and need to be run. i am using angular material also primeng components in my applications

You might need to check if you have imported the required lib. in the module where you get the error.

I have imported all modules in module.ts
